Ubuntu 20.04 and 24.04 freeze on installation
I have a new SuperMicro 7049GP-TRT server. (general specs at https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/system/4u/7049/sys-7049gp-trt.cfm)
The SuperMicro 7049GP-TRT is certified for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04.
This machine has Dual Xeon Gold 6140 processors, 96 GB DDR4 (6×16 GB), a 1 TB WD 770 NVMe, and four 1 TB SSD. The BIOS is set to UEFI only (the only change I made, from DUAL). The BIOS sees all drives.
I used both Rufus and Etcher to put both 20.04.6 and 24.04.1 onto a Kingston 128 GB USB. In Rufus, I set the partition scheme to GPT, which sets a UEFI target. No matter the configuration, installation fails immediately.
Etcher with 20.04

SuperMicro screen is smaller with Ubuntu name below. Text checks a bunch of files.
Switches to a blank black screen. Stays like this over 10 minutes.

Etcher with 24.04

Flashes "Checking media preferences .............." several times.
Dumps to UEFI Interaction Shell 2.2

Rufus with 20.04

After selecting "Try or install Ubuntu", trainsitions to smaller SuperMicro screen
with Ubuntu name below. Text checks a bunch of files.
Switches to a blank black screen. Stays like this over 10 minutes.

The second and third times I tried the 20.04 installation, it gave the "Checking media preferences .............." several times, then dumbed UEFI Interaction Shell 2.2
Rufus with 24.04

After selecting "Try or install Ubuntu", transitions to smaller SuperMicro screen
with Ubuntu name below. (No obvious file checking.)
Switches to a blank black screen. Stays like this over 10 minutes.

Suggestions?

RHEL 9.5 works flawlessly to the installation page.
